Material Design Load Files Error in WPF and XAML
i'm trying to add Materia Design in to my WPF app and when i want to add resource dictionary to App.xaml with this codes:
<ResourceDictionary>
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>

i give errors on each 4 lines.
The errors are as follows:
First code line error:

Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   XDG0010 Could not load file or assembly 'MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  Supabase1   D:\Apps\Supabase1\Supabase1\App.xaml    9

Second code line error:

Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   XDG0010 Could not load file or assembly 'MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  Supabase1   D:\Apps\Supabase1\Supabase1\App.xaml    10

Third code line error:

Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   XDG0010 Could not load file or assembly 'MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  Supabase1   D:\Apps\Supabase1\Supabase1\App.xaml    10

Fourth code line error:

Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   XDG0010 Could not load file or assembly 'MaterialDesignColors, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  Supabase1   D:\Apps\Supabase1\Supabase1\App.xaml    12

Even though I installed the MaterialDesignThemes and MaterialDesignColors packages.
Please HELP me:(

Did you include the MaterialDesign nuget package into your solution/project?
